# Can the word "immerse" be used in negative situations?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I want to express the idea of someone being addicted to video games. Can I say something as follows?

> He tends to immerse himself in video games.

> He tends to be sunk in video games.

> he tends to be drown in video games.

Thank you

Comment: The first is much the most idiomatic. The third should read _to be drowned_, but 'drown' in its metaphorical sense means 'have more than you can cope with'.

Comment: Or 'he gets hypnotized' by them, maybe.